# Actionscript style events in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, actionscript

I'm a newbie doing Objective-C, coming from Flex/Actionscript development.

I have an iPhone app with an UIApplicationDelegate conforming delegate called MyAppDelegate - it has a UIWindow.

Instead of adding buttons, labels and whatnot directly to the window, I guess I'm supposed to make a child class of UIViewController for every screen I wanna make. When that screen should be displayed, I add the respective controller's view to the window as a subview. When another screen should be displayed, I should pop off any other view from the window and add the new view. Hope I got everything correct so far...

My intent is to make each view controller only know about its own things, so let's say I wanna call view A from view B, in ActionScript I'd add a button in A firing off an event which would be caught in view A's owning object (could be the application), which could take proper action (remove view A, instantiate view B and display it).

How do I do this in Objective-C?

Comment: The basic concept/pattern you describe is the Responder Chain. The iOS SDK implements that internally for you, allowing you to specify a "nil" target (no target) and an action for a control (button etc). The button's action will "bubble" through the responder chain allowing each object a chance to handle it.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the answer I ended up making use of. However can't "check" it ;-)
Even though the other answers on this page all are correct, it all depends on the app and circumstances...
What I did: In the nib file of page1, I clicked on First Responder, went to "Responder Identity" and added a new action "goPage2:". Then I hooked that up with a button on page1. In the page1 controller, I was able to catch the event. However I moved the catching function to the "parent" controller, and it works. Enough for now, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIControl, such as UIButton, can have any number of event listeners registered with:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

The target would be the view controller you want to receive the method, and the action is the method you want called.  For a button, events is usually just `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.  If the target is nil, the event will pass up the responder chain until a responder implements the action.  If you pass `@selector(buttonClicked:)` then the target should have this method:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender;
```

The sender will be the button that was clicked.  IBAction is equivalent to a void return type.  You can bind the action in Interface Builder if you prefer that to doing it programmatically.

> When another screen should be
>   displayed, I should pop off any other
>   view from the window and add the new
>   view.

This is basically correct, but usually you use a meta view controller like `UINavigationController` to manage view controllers.  Even if you do not use the UI that a meta controller might present, it is convenient to have view switching managed for you.

Comment: Like you note, I've now seen that using UINavigationController (or the tab controller) would be preferred. These controllers however always (more or less) stay visible on screen, ie you have a bar on top or bottom containing main nav buttons. My app however is a doc viewer, where viewing the document is central (could consume lots of memory), still after long contemplating I didn't find a ready-made controller for this. The doc view would be the first on launch, and should take 100% of the screen, without nav bars. On another view, I want to unload the document view completely to save memory.

Comment: With a navigation controller, use `navigationBarHidden=YES` to hide the navigation bar.  Set it from `viewWillAppear:` of each controller that is pushed.

Comment: Meta view controllers add and remove the views of view controllers they show.  After `viewDidDisappear:` is called, you are free to release any views and other resources as long as you can create them again in `loadView` or `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're coming from Actionscript you may be interested in looking at the [PureMVC framwork for objective C](http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_ObjectiveC).  Using PureMVC you'll create a combination of Mediators, Commands, and Models for application interaction.

With PureMVC you register notification with the `facade`, and you define listeners in your mediators to respond to these.  This is pretty close to the event model you're used to in Actionscript.  (At my last job we added some categories to the `UIResponder` to remove some of the cruft in doing this).  If you're creating a considerably sized application, then I would recommend you give it a look; it certainly helped us keep everything manageable.

If you don't want to pull in a third party library then you should define your view manipulation code in your `MyAppDelegate` and use the [`[UIApplication sharedApplication]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIApplication/sharedApplication) class method to access the globally shared instance.